# Rollover Text not display in all items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code that includes a 5 boxes all lined up next to eachother with a hyperlink and a mouseover text. The code appear to work on the first box but not on the rest but not on the rest of the items.

```html
<!--DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"-->
<title>Hide/Show</title>
<style type="text/css">
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
  }
  div#page {
    margin: 40px auto;
    border: 1px solid #f9fefc;
    width: 9px;
  }
  .TogWrap {
    width: 220px;
    padding: 2px;
  }
  #togTrigger {
    border: 1px solid #bebebe;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    background: #e7f5fc;
    color: #ddddd;
  }
  .togContent {
    margin-top: 2px;
    border: 1px #;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: #ededed;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!-- HIDE FROM OLD BROWSERS
  /* <![CDATA[ */

  var oVTog = {
    toggle: function(el) {
      oVTog.container = el.parentNode;
      oVTog.para = oVTog.container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
      oVTog.para.style.display = "none";

      el.onmouseover = function() {
        oVTog.para.style.display = '';
        return false;
      };
      el.onmouseout = function() {
        oVTog.para.style.display = 'none';
        return false;
      };
      el.onclick = function() {
        oVTog.para.style.display = oVTog.para.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
  window.onload = function() {
    var l = document.getElementById('togTrigger');
    oVTog.toggle(l);
  };

  /* ]]> */
  //END HIDING -->
</script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
          <a id="togTrigger" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/Active%20CS%20Submission.aspx">Active</a>
          <p class="togContent" style="display: none;">This list contains claimed and unclaimed submissions</p>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
          <a id="togTrigger" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/Active%20CS%20Submission.aspx">All (Without Attachments</a> 
          <p class="togContent" style="display: none;">Contains all active submissions</p>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
          <a id="togTrigger" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/Attachment.aspx">Email Attachments</a> 
          <p class="togContent" style="display: none;">All attchments to submissions</p>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
          <a id="togTrigger" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/AllItems.aspx">Returned Submissions</a>
          <p class="togContent" style="display: none;">All Submissions that have been reviewed and returned for additional information</p>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
          <a id="togTrigger" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/Logged%20Into%20CS%20Tracker.aspx">Logged Into CS Tracker</a> 
          <p class="togContent" style="display: none;">All Submssions that have been entered into CS Tracker</p>
        </div>
      </th>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: All your IDs are duplicated. You can not do that. Also your HTML is missing the HTML, HEAD and BODY elements.

Comment: The line in your window.onload function: var l = document.getElementById('togTrigger');  will only return the first element with that ID.

Comment: Hello Everyone Thanks for all the tips. I'm really new to this so I'm learning as requirements come up.  I've made some progress my code now will display rollover text for each item.  Thanks to all your suggestions. But I've now am having problem with a hyperlink. I need reach item to have a hyperlink and a rollover (which is working).

Answer (score 1):

you cannot have elements with same ID on the page and run JavaScript

Use JQuery and apply the hover on classes instead of ID

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple elements with the same id (togTrigger).

Try using togTrigger1 through togTrigger5 and repeat or loop the relevant activation code for all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on the differences between using an `ID` and a `class`

There are 2 important distinctions to make, that being a `class` can be used multiple times in a single HTML page, while an `ID` can only be used once, otherwise it will cause unwanted behavior.

See the edited code below for more help, and guidance.

```js
    var oVTog = {
        toggle: function(el) {
          oVTog.container = el.parentNode;
          oVTog.para = oVTog.container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
          oVTog.para.style.display = "none";

          el.onmouseover = function() {
            oVTog.para.style.display = '';
            return false;
          };
          el.onmouseout = function() {
            oVTog.para.style.display = 'none';
            return false;
          };
          el.onclick = function() {
            oVTog.para.style.display = oVTog.para.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none';
            return false;
          };
        }
      };
      window.onload = function() {
        var l = document.getElementsByClassName('togTrigger');
        oVTog.toggle(l[0]);
      };
```

```css
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: none;
      }
      div#page {
        margin: 40px auto;
        border: 1px solid #f9fefc;
        width: 9px;
      }
      .TogWrap {
        width: 220px;
        padding: 2px;
      }
      #togTrigger {
        border: 1px solid #bebebe;
        padding: 1px 5px;
        background: #e7f5fc;
        color: #ddddd;
      }
      .togContent {
        margin-top: 2px;
        border: 1px #;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        background: #ededed;
      }
```

```html
   <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
              <a class="togTrigger" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/Active%20CS%20Submission.aspx">Active</a>
              <p class="togContent" style="display: none;">This list contains claimed and unclaimed submissions</p>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
              <a class="togTrigger" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/Active%20CS%20Submission.aspx">All (Without Attachments</a> 
              <p class="togContent" style="display: none;">Contains all active submissions</p>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
              <a class="togTrigger" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/Attachment.aspx">Email Attachments</a> 
              <p class="togContent" style="display: none;">All attchments to submissions</p>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
              <a class="togTrigger" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/AllItems.aspx">Returned Submissions</a>
              <p class="togContent" style="display: none;">All Submissions that have been reviewed and returned for additional information</p>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th>
            <div class="TogWrap" id="theTog">
              <a class="togTrigger" href="/sites/pm/CS_Submissions/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/CS_Submissions_Inbox/Forms/Logged%20Into%20CS%20Tracker.aspx">Logged Into CS Tracker</a> 
              <p class="togContent" style="display: none;">All Submssions that have been entered into CS Tracker</p>
            </div>
          </th>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```